# How to Add Dollar Sign on the RIght hand Side of the Textfield in Flutter App

Tags: flutter

how can we achieve like... Added Below Example for it..

https://i.imgur.com/fzwvHte.mp4

[image: want to like this]

This is the Code I am Working on it.

```
Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text("Exchange"),
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Container(
                        width: width / 2,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: "0",
                              isDense: true,
                              prefix: Text(
                                "\$",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              ),
                              prefixStyle: TextStyle()),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: Hey did you figure this out i have the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

If your keyboard doesn't have a dollar sign then you could use the unicode character:\u0024[image: Result after using unicode]

```
Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("\u0024 2500"),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: can u show me the With TextField Example & with Dollar Sign like Above video

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the suffixIcon property ?

`suffixIcon: Text('$')`

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work ^^ ?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> **This is how can u do it on your code . thanks**
> ```

```
 Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text("Exchange"),
                          SizedBox(width: 20),
                          Container(
                            width: width / 2,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: "0",
                                  isDense: true,
                                  suffixIcon: Text('$'),
                                  ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
```

Comment: thanks for help But I want to add Dollar sign infront of the Number Not after the Number... you can check Video example for it...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the inputFormatters to achieve this as follows:

```
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text("Exchange"),
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Container(
                        width: width / 2,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            TextInputFormatter.withFunction(oldValue,newValue)=>
                              newValue.copyWith(text:newValue.text.contains("$") ?newValue.text : "\$ ${newValue.text}")
                             ]
                    
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```